# Jackson Json Parser- How to handle exceptions for value not found

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

Quick background: I have built a simple Spring REST API based around a simple JSON file. Ive used Jackson to parse the JSON. The API itself works fine. For example when I enter the necessary ID it returns the desired fields.
Im having trouble with exception handling. So if I enter movies/7 for example (There is no movie with ID 7) It just returns an empty body.
What code do I need to get it to throw an exception instead?
Please find code below:

MovieService.java

```
1. @Component
2. public class MovieService {
3. 
4.     ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
5. 
6.     public Movie findAll() throws IOException {
7. 
8.         byte[] jsonData = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("movies.json"));
9. 
10.             Movie movie = objectMapper.readValue(jsonData, Movie.class);
11.             return movie;
12. 
13.     }
14. 
15.     public Movies findMovie(int id) throws IOException {
16. 
17.         byte[] jsonData = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("movies.json"));
18.         Movie movie = objectMapper.readValue(jsonData, Movie.class);
19. 
20.             for (Movies movies : movie.getMovies()) {
21.                 if (movies.getMovieId() == id) {
22. 
23.                     return movies;
24.                 }
25.             }
26. 
27.             return null;
28.     }
29. }
```

MovieController.java

```
1. @RestController
2.     public class MovieController {
3.     
4.         @Autowired
5.         private MovieService movieService;
6.     
7.         @GetMapping
8.         @RequestMapping("/movies")
9.         public Movies[] getAll() throws IOException {
10.     
11.                 Movies[] response = movieService.findAll().getMovies();
12.                 return response;
13.     
14.         }
15.     
16.         @GetMapping
17.         @RequestMapping("/movies/{id}")
18.         public Movies getMovie(@PathVariable int id) throws IOException {
19.     
20.             Movies response = movieService.findMovie(id);
21.             return response;
22.         }
23. }
```

Like I said, the code works absolutely fine. But what if statement/ try-catch do i need to implement to get the exceptions to throw?

Comment: #1 What is the value of response when you enter an id 7 :  Movies response = movieService.findMovie(7);   Null?? #2 When you say **empty body**, do you mean : {}, or a kind of error 500, 400, etc ? #3 There are a couple of improvements If you let me

Comment: @JRichardsz I just get a {}.

Comment: When id is 7, response var is null in line 21 in MovieController.java ? If is null , do you need to detect it and show a custom message in your json?

Comment: @JRichardsz you were absoilutely right. I was trying to use try catch blocks but i used an if statement instead to detect the null

Comment: So, Did you solve your problem? If you add this to your question "Is there another ways to handle errors?" , I'd be happy to share you some tips

Answer (score 0):

Use @ExceptionHandler to throw exception from service level.

```
@ExceptionHandler(NoDataException.class)
public ResponseEntity handleException(NoDataException e) {
    return new ResponseEntity("No Data Found", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Throw `NoDataException` from wherever you want to handle specific exception.

Read more from here - https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

Comment: But then where in my controller or service do i implement this?